# Android Device long-press causing an underlying link to fire when an overlay div is closed

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, long-press

I have a fixed overlay div with a high z-index showing a gallery of images. There is a close button in the top right corner which closes the overlay gallery.

Unfortunately, the website has a fixed top bar header with a facebook social icon using an anchor tag and font-awesome icon. The facebook link is positioned EXACTLY underneath the gallery close button. Closing the overlay gallery on an android device causes the underlying facebook anchor link to fire as well, taking the user to facebook. Evidently, two clicks are being registered, one for the overlay close anchor and another for the facebook icon link.

The problem doesn't seem to occur on iPhone devices. On one of the phones I tested, the gallery closes without causing the facebook link to fire.

At the present, I'm resorting to nasty hacks like setting the facebook link href to javascript:void(0) when the gallery is opened, and then correcting the link when the gallery is closed using a javascript timer delay. It prevents the facebook link from firing, but the facebook anchor tag is still getting a click/hover which causes the hover effect to fire, thus causing the css :hover styling to apply.

Is there any easy solution to this problem or a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the issue by creating a transparent overlay div on top of the facebook icon when the gallery is opened, and then removed it 300ms after the gallery was closed.

:/